# Why won't these strings concatenate in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, string-concatenation

I have an example of two test programs I wrote in C++. The first one works fine, the first one errors. Please help me to explain what is going on here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string randomStrGen(int length) {
static string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
string result;
result.resize(length);
for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    result[i] = charset[rand() % charset.length()];
return result;
}

int main()
{
ofstream pConf;
pConf.open("test.txt");
pConf << "rpcuser=user\nrpcpassword=" 
     + randomStrGen(15)
     + "\nrpcport=14632"
     + "\nrpcallowip=127.0.0.1"
     + "\nport=14631"
     + "\ndaemon=1"
     + "\nserver=1"
     + "\naddnode=107.170.59.196";
pConf.close();
return 0;
}
```

It opens 'test.txt' and writes the data, no problem. This, however, does not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string randomStrGen(int length) {
static string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
string result;
result.resize(length);
for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    result[i] = charset[rand() % charset.length()];
return result;
}

int main()
{
ofstream pConf;
pConf.open("test.txt");
pConf << "rpcuser=user\n"
     + "rpcpassword=" 
     + randomStrGen(15)
     + "\nrpcport=14632"
     + "\nrpcallowip=127.0.0.1"
     + "\nport=14631"
     + "\ndaemon=1"
     + "\nserver=1"
     + "\naddnode=107.170.59.196";
pConf.close();
return 0;
}
```

The only difference in the second program is that 'rpcpassword' has been moved to the next line.

```
matthew@matthew-Satellite-P845:~/Desktop$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:23:6: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [14]’ and ‘const char [13]’ to binary ‘operator+’ 
  + "rpcpassword="
```

Comment: The difference is `std::string` has `operator+` overloaded for concatenation with `const char*`.

Comment: Aasmund's answer's right, but incidentally adjacent string literals gets concatenated by the compiler in a pretty early phase (e.g. "abc" "def" becomes "abcdef", even if they're on different lines in the source).  So, if you remove all the '+'s except those before and after `randomStrGen(15)`, it will not only compile properly but use less memory and run faster.

Comment: FWIW - example using concatenation [here](http://ideone.com/MEoMgF)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"rpcuser=user\nrpcpassword=" + randomStrGen(15) + "\nrpcport=14632"` groups like `("rpcuser=user\nrpcpassword=" + randomStrGen(15)) + "\nrpcport=14632"`.  Here, `+` is always used with an argument of a class type, so you get `std::string::operator+` after overload resolution.

`"rpcuser=user\n" + "rpcpassword=" + randomStrGen(15)` groups like `("rpcuser=user\n" + "rpcpassword=") + randomStrGen(15)`.  In this case, the first `+` is used on two non-class types, so it's not overloaded and the language doesn't define `+` for two `const char []` values.  (I come from old C, so I was a bit it didn't just add them as `char *`s and give you a nice SIGSEGV at runtime.)

Comment: Both answers were very helpful, your groupings with the parentheses made it click. I don't like the fact that it is overloading without me knowing about it, it seems this will lead to programmers not knowing exactly what is going on. I will make sure to change my use of string literals.

Comment: I should have used parentheses to make my point more clear, so this gets an upvote from me too :-) (As long as you're using C++, you better get used to overloading...)

Answer (score 5):

A string literal (`"foo"`) in C++ is *not* of the type `string`; it is of the type `const char[x]`, where `x` is the length of the string literal plus 1. And character arrays can't be joined with `+`. However, a character array *can* be joined with a `string`, and the result is a `string`, which may further be joined with character arrays. Therefore, `"a" + functionThatReturnsString() + "b"` works, but `"a" + "b"` does not. (Keep in mind that `+` is left associative; it is applied to the two leftmost operands first, and then to the result and the third operand, and so on.)

Comment: The OP should just remove the `+` as two consecutive string literals are automatically concatenated.

Comment: @user2676680 There are many [non-member overloads for `operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) which take a `const char*` and a `std::string`. However, there is no built-in `operator+` which takes two `const char*`s.

Comment: @user2676680 The last 2 sentences explain why the first one works

Comment: In case this did not become clear from @remyabel's comment: They are concatenated during translation of the program so it also has zero run-time overhead.  If you don't have literals, you can replace your `+` with `<<` but it will be less efficient in your current case.